# Describing grammar language / which language does this automaton recognize

Tags: computer-science, automata

I'm studying some questions about Automaton / Regular Expressions and I'm stuck in these questions.

---

Question 54

Which language does the automaton below recognize?

[Automaton image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHgCq.png)

I tried trial and error, but I couldn't get any good results.

---

Question 66

a) Present 3 words generated by the grammar below. Show the sequence of
rules used for the generation of word.

```
S → bS | aA | ϵ
A → bA | aS
```

My awnser:

```
S -> bS -> baA -> baaS -> baaϵ -> baa
S -> aA -> aaS -> aaϵ -> aa
S -> aA -> abA -> abaS -> abaϵ -> aba
```

b) Describe what language this grammar generates.

I tried to find a pattern to describe the language, but I couldn't.

---

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For question 54: Notice that when you are in q_1 and q_3 you always have the choice to stay here (since a and b both leads to the same state). This suggests that what is in the "middle" of the words does not matter much. Try to look for patterns in the words by only looking at the first and last letters of each words.

Comment: For question 66: Notice that to get an "A" from a "S" you must use the rule S → aA, and to get a "S" from a "A" you must use the rule A → aS (and that in both case you get an additional a).
Now the only way to stop the process is to get rid of all non-terminal symbols (that is A and S). This is only possible through the rule S → ϵ. Meaning that every time you get from an "S" to an "A", you must go back and go from an "A" to an "S" (to then go to ϵ). Try to count the number of "a" that can appear in the words you can generate in the grammar and see if you can spot a pattern. Good luck!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I see multiple questions here.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask each one separately, in its own post.